# How to use War3chart tool

Tags: warcraft-3

I feel really silly but I can't figure how to use it. I did read FAQ, but there is nothing about basic usage there.

Basically I open program, load the replay, and that's it. I don't see charts or anything else. The only thing that is shown is the name of the map played. What am I missing?

I'm running Windows 7 (I did try to run it in WinXP compatibility mode, also as an administrator) and Warcraft client version 1.24e.

Edit: after scanning entire folders, it seems War3Chart thinks that all but 2 of my replays are corrupted. Some are downloaded or my own, some are multi-player or versus AI. I doubt that War3Chart is right, how so many replays can be corrupted? :(

Comment: I do not know the tool you use (could it be w3chart), but if you have an old version it might not work with recent patches. There are a ton of other apps like this. I remember wc3master. But with the community falling apart many sites went down and I am not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that this question is very old, but War3Chart hasn't worked since 1.22 (at least for my computers). It has not gotten updated, but there are some other tools you can use. My favorite is an online tool called [W3Rep](http://w3rep.sourceforge.net/example.php)

Comment: Thank you. The post may be old but War3 will never get old :)